# date_time_set issue with 2 different dates

Tags: php, date, datetime, datetime-format

I'm trying to set the time between 2 variables but when I check it copies the change on the 2 time. For example, I select 1:00 and 23:00 , both dates show 23:00 only. I can't seem to get why it's showing like that even if I have already different variables for each time. I need to show the different dates.

Input Dates:

```
01:30 and 21:00
```

My code:

```
$date = $_POST['datepicker'];

$time1 = $_POST['timepicker'];
$time2 = $_POST['timepicker2'];

$time1_array = explode(":",$time1);
$time2_array = explode(":",$time2);

$date = $_POST['datepicker'];

$date = new DateTime($date);
$date2 = $date;
$datefinal1 = date_time_set($date, $time1_array[0], $time1_array[1], 00);
$datefinal2 = date_time_set($date2,  $time2_array[0], $time2_array[1], 59);
$result = $datefinal1->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$result2 = $datefinal2->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
print_r($datefinal1);
```

Sample output that I am getting:

> DateTime Object ( [date] => 2015-03-17 21:00:59 [timezone_type] => 3
>   [timezone] => Europe/Berlin )

even if I should be getting the $datefinal2's value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objects are copied by reference, not value. If you assign one object to a new variable both point to the same object so changing one changes the other. To copy an object you need to use `clone`.

```
$date2 = $date;
```

should be:

```
$date2 = clone $date;
```

Comment: it's my first time to encounter clone in php, I just checked and it works now.

Comment: How about `$date2 = new DateTime($date);` ?